# How do I get image from Profile Model

Tags: python, django

How can I get the image from Profile Model link with foreignkey User. I tried `{% for user in users %}{{ user.profile_pic }}{% endfor %}` with img src this do not display the image.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePicture/', blank=True)

users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need create a profile model and fill some data to profile model.
then access the profile data on template.

[this is my model check it out first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BHqK.png)

then you  need to make settings in settings.py for media urls.
[settings.py settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWIpd.png)

now make a basic view for that 
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLy63.png)

finally make your template like  this 
[base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlZi2.png)

and this is my final results 
 [final result of profile pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5HHf.png)

this is my Project Directory [Project Folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZgLD.png)

if you still didn't understand feel free to ask Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm more of a flask/SQLAlchemy user than a django user, but I believe the principle is quite similar. `Profile` is a model that maps to the database, `profile_pic` is an attribute referencing the `ImageField` class, and your template file should have a call not the `ImageField` instance but to the attribute of that instance that stores the full location of the image file. So in your example, the call would be something like this:

```
{% for user in users %}
<img src="{{ user.profile_pic.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

I believe you also want to use `filter` rather than `exclude` in your query statement, unless I am misunderstanding the desired result. `filter` would get you the model where the id variable matches the current user's id. `exclude` would return all others but not the current user.

Comment: I used filter and also the image do not display.